# How to get struts.multipart.maxSize at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, struts2, xml-configuration

Can be obtained at runtime the `struts.multipart.maxSize` value defined in `struts.xml`?

using Struts2

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done the following way. Add this code to the action or bean managed by Struts container. For other beans you should use the container to inject dependencies.

```
private String multipartMaxSize;

@Inject(StrutsConstants.STRUTS_MULTIPART_MAXSIZE)
public void setMultipartMaxSize(String multipartMaxSize) {
  this.multipartMaxSize = multipartMaxSize;
}
```